# How do I restrict who can run my GCP Cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I've been working with GCP's cloud functions, but I'm concerned about them being exposed to the wide internet through HTTP.

Is there a way to restrict who can successfully run a GCP hosted cloud function? E.g. through authentication, or some clever usage of tokens.

The outcome I want is for my web-apps to be able to run the cloud function, but I don't want anyone to be able to get the right output.

I thought of including some authentication in the cloud function's code (e.g. checking a cookie, or token against something) but I'm looking to not reinvent the wheel.

Any advice?

Comment: Google has documentation covering Functions security https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **IAM roles**.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles) you can see all the roles that you can grant to each user.

In your case, I assume you need the `cloudfunctions.invoker` role.

You can also set a condition when granting the role and select the `condition type` to be based on the `Resource Name` so you can set different roles on each function.